# its rather unheralded premiere on Netflix suggests something of a stinker

Tags: meaning-in-context

> There are plenty of reasons to be entirely uninterested in the arrival of Hush. First, it’s yet another tale of home invasion, a subgenre overly populated with substandard variations on the same damn story. Second, it’s from the Blumhouse stable, a production company that’s been spreading itself far too thin of late with pointless remakes (Martyrs) and dreary sequels (Sinister 2) threatening a once-strong brand name. **Third, its rather unheralded premiere on Netflix suggests something of a stinker**.
>
> (Source: http://www.theguardian.com/film/2016/apr/14/hush-review-nifty-home-invasion-thriller-mike-flanagan-kate-siegel-john-gallagher-jr)

What do you think is meant by the bold passage providing the third reason why the reviewed movie could be viewed as the trash. The one and only explanation resides in my opinion in the fact that the movie was put on the programme of Netflix (everything what appears on Netflix is of a low artistic level) which I find given the fact what kind of production this television offers at least odd.  So how do you interpret the bold passage?

Comment: Not just the fact that it was on Netflix, but its **rather unheralded premiere** - that is, the producers did not try to publicize it very much.  That might mean they know it's not very good.

Comment: @stangdon To me, *unheralded* also suggests that there was not much buzz from the press/critics about it, further indicating it's not very good.

Comment: Remember to cite the sources of passages you quote.

Comment: Everything put on Netflix is not low artistic level. There have been [several Netflix series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_original_programs_distributed_by_Netflix)  that have gotten lots of praise and publicity in the past one or two years. And there is still a sizeable selection, but certainly not as wide a selection as previously  or so it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what Stangdon said, it's the **unheralded premiere** that's the important part.

The relevant definition of herald here is "*To proclaim, especially with enthusiasm; announce or acclaim*". The implication the article makes is that if the movie was good, the producers, critics, and fans of the movie would be making some noise about it.